# Python's initialization a list in a class

Tags: python, class

I don't understand python's behavior, I've got many the same errors:

> File "./start.py", line 20, in print2
>      item.print2()
>   RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

My code is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Component:
    def print2(self):
        pass

class Composite(Component):
    items = []
    name = 'composite'

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def print2(self):
        if self.items:
            for item in self.items:
                item.print2()
        else:
            print self.name

class Leaf(Component):
    name = 'leaf'

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def print2(self):
        print self.name

category = Composite('category1')
leaf = Composite('leaf1')
category.add(leaf)
leaf = Leaf('leaf2')
category.add(leaf)

category.print2()
```

When I add `self.items = []` in the constructor ( `__init__` ), it works fine. Could you explain the behavior?

Comment: Because all your objects are sharing `items`... that is a *class variable*, i.e. "static"

Comment: Elements outside of `__init__` are static elements belonging to the class, elements inside of `__init__` are members of the object, they do not belong to the class.  Which means that every time you call `print2()`, regardless of the object, `self.items` contains 2 Composites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`items` is a class variable, so it is shared by every instance of `Composite`.  When you `append` into `items`, all instances get that item.  So after adding the `leaf`s, you have:

```
   Type                    Composite.items
------------------------------------------
 Composite    category1    [leaf1, leaf2]
                  |
 Composite      leaf1      [leaf1, leaf2]
                  |
      Leaf      leaf2
```

If `print2` is called on `leaf1`, it will try to call `print2` on each of the `items` in the class, which includes `leaf1` again, and again, in an infinite recursion.

If you instead initialize `self.items = []` inside `__init__`, it will be an instance variable instead of a class variable, so each `Composite` will have its own list of `items`.

Answer (score 6):

Because all your objects are sharing items... that is a class variable, i.e. "static"

```
class Foo:
    # <anything assigned here is static>
    static_var1 = 'foo'
    def some_method(self, bar):
        self.x = bar # this is an *instance* variable
```

so in:

```
def print2(self):
    if self.items:
        for item in self.items:
            item.print2()
```

It iterates over the static `items`. Note:

```
In [11]: category.items
Out[11]: [<__main__.Composite at 0x103078978>, <__main__.Leaf at 0x103078ac8>]

In [12]: category.items[0].name
Out[12]: 'leaf1'
```

When you hit that first item, it calls `item.print2()`, which then starts iterating over `items`, and it hits `'leaf1'` again, which *again* calls `item.print2()`...

Note, Python's object model is pretty simple, `instance.method()` is equivalent to `InstanceClass.method(instance)`, i.e., the only "magic" that happens in methods is that if a method is accessed through an instance, what is actually returned is a *bound method*, which has bound the instance as the first argument to the function. So note:

```
In [15]: class Foo:
    ...:     def mutate(self, x):
    ...:         self.foo = x
    ...:

In [16]: f = Foo()

In [17]: f.mutate(42)

In [18]: f.foo
Out[18]: 42

In [19]: Foo.mutate(f, 99)

In [20]: f.foo
Out[20]: 99
```

Note, `Foo.mutate` is *just a function*. It doesn't care about what `self` actually is:

```
In [21]: class Bar:
    ...:     pass
    ...:

In [22]: b = Bar()

In [23]: Foo.mutate(b, 'foooooo')

In [24]: b.foo
Out[24]: 'foooooo'
```

Little bit of arcana, every single time a method is accessed, an *entirely new* bound-method object is created:

```
In [34]: f.mutate
Out[34]: <bound method Foo.mutate of <__main__.Foo object at 0x1030641d0>>

In [35]: methods = f.mutate, f.mutate, f.mutate

In [36]: [hex(id(m)) for m in methods]
Out[36]: ['0x10581de08', '0x10581d208', '0x105abc988']
```

Which leads to the seemingly weird:

```
In [37]: f.mutate is f.mutate
Out[37]: False
```

However, that wraps the same underlying function, `Foo.mutate`, which doesn't change, and is simply an attribute like any other on a class:

```
In [38]: Foo.mutate is Foo.mutate
Out[38]: True
```

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is two things
1. items was created as a class variable
2. leaf1 was added as a Component: `Composite('leaf1')` and therefore possesses the class variable `items`

These two together mean that leaf1.print2() will recursively call itself forever