# for list of object in list of object problem python

Tags: python, sql, list, object

I have created 2 class , I need have 1 list of one class inside another class. This class is generated from database select

I have a problem with iterating objects list inside objects list:

**MySQL Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE tablefruit (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    shopid INT(6) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE tableshop (
    shopid INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
);


TABLE CONTENTS:
-- tablefruit
id  shopid  name    description
1   1       ftest1  ftestdesc1
2   1       ftest2  ftestdesc2  

-- tableshop
shopid  name        description
1       stest1      stestdesc1
2       stest2      stestdesc2
3       stest3      stestdesc3

"""
```

**Python code**

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

connection = None

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                         database='database',
                         user='root',
                         password='password',autocommit=True)
    if connection.is_connected():
       db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
       print("Connected to MySQL database... MySQL Server version on ",db_Info)
except Error as e :
    print ("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)


class fruit:
    id=None
    shopid=None
    name=None
    description=None

    def db_select(self):
        sql = "select shopid,name,description from tablefruit where id = %s"
        val = (self.id,)
        cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
        cursor.execute(sql,val)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in records:
            self.shopid =       row[0]
            self.name =         row[1]
            self.description =  row[2]
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()

    def __init__(self,id=None)
        self.id=id
        self.db_select()

class shop:
    shopid=None
    name=None
    description=None
    fruits = list()

    def db_select(self):
        sql = "select name,description from tableshop where shopid = %s"
        val = (self.shopid,)
        cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
        cursor.execute(sql,val)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in records:
            self.name           = row[0]
            self.description    = row[1]
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()

    def load_fruit(self):
        sql = "select id from tablefruit where shopid = %s"
        val = (self.shopid,)
        cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
        cursor.execute(sql,val)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in records:
            fruits.append(fruit(row[0]))
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()

    def __init__(self,shopid=None):        
        self.shopid=shopid
        self.db_select()
        self.load_fruit()


#MAIN
shops=list()

sql = "select shopid from tablefruit"
cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
cursor.execute(sql)
records = cursor.fetchall()
for row in records:
    shops.append(shop(row[0]))
cursor.close()
connection.commit()

for shop in shops:
    for fruit in shop.fruits:
        print(fruit.name,fruit.description)
```

My code : https://pastebin.com/0Qck4FbH

and my output is:

```
ftest1  ftestdesc1
ftest2  ftestdesc2
ftest1  ftestdesc1
ftest2  ftestdesc2
ftest1  ftestdesc1
ftest2  ftestdesc2
```

why is this the output? The output I expect would be:

```
ftest1  ftestdesc1
ftest2  ftestdesc2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED** 
source answare: [Python's initialization a list in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040518/pythons-initialization-a-list-in-a-class)

I just set the class list as empty at class init.

```
def __init__(self,shopid=None):
        self.fruits=[] # <<< <<< <<<
        self.shopid=shopid
        self.db_select()
        self.load_fruit()
```